# cakePHP incorrect datetime format

Tags: mysql, datetime, cakephp, timestamp

I am new to cakePHP.

Currently I am facing this trouble, it show me this error when I login to cakePHP project.

```
**Database Error**
Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2015-10-22T15:42:20+08:00' for column 'last_login' at row 1

SQL Query: UPDATE `cakephpdb`.`users` SET `last_login` = '2015-10-22T15:42:20+08:00', `modified` = '2015-10-22 15:42:20' WHERE `cakephpdb`.`users`.`id` = '37'
```

I think this can be configure in cakePHP config file (which just edit in 1 file that can affect the entire project) or maybe change the MySQL setting.

**Below is detail:**

- CakePHP project: Hosted and run in IIS server
- MySQL: in another server
- MySQL version: 5.5.38

Many thanks for help! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2015-10-22T15:42:20+08:00'

Pass the *correct* datetime format: `YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` This is what I would assume the field expects. Use `date()` to reformat your date or the `DateTime` class of whatever CakePHP version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the format of datatime you are trying to pass is the issue.

Make it change with PHP date function in proper format **(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)**.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($yourdate));
```

I think this will work in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird that if I am using **XAMPP at localhost**, it can be store perfectly. But when I launch in live (using IIS), it can't store with this datetime format "2015-10-22T15:42:20+08:00".

So I found out that cakePHP is using:

> date(DATE_ATOM)

I change it to:

> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

now is it worked.

Thanks to @burzum and @Chandresh. :)

Comment: Please accept an answer (yes, even this one) - don't edit the question to say "solved". Note however that DATE_ATOM [doesn't seem to be in CakePHP at all](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DATE_ATOM) - this answer doesn't make sense.